# Is it possible to create text field in pdf form which can grow in size as per text bind to it?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a task where i have to bind text dynamically to pdf form text field. The form must be flowed as well as text field also should be flowed. is it possible?. The text size is not fixed and i want to bind it to that text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible with AcroForm technology, so if you want pure PDF forms, the answer is no: the position and size of every field are fixed at absolute coordinates on the page.

It is only possible with XFA technology (XML Forms Architecture), but in this case, the form is defined using XML wrapped in a PDF file. XFA is deprecated in PDF 2.0. There aren't many tools available to create an XFA form. You can create such a form with Adobe LiveCycle Designer (although it's not easy to use), and you can fill and flatten such a form using iText's pdfXFA add-on.

Summarized; the short answer is "No". The long answer is: if you want to use deprecated technology and find the right tools, the answer is "Yes, but I would not recommend it."

It's a better idea to create a template using HTML and CSS, populate the HTML with data, and then use iText's pdfHTML tool to convert the HTML and CSS to PDF.